# Showing that if $g$ is a primitive root $\pmod{p^2}$, then it is a primitive root $\pmod{p}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to show that if $g$ is a primitive root $\pmod{p^2}$, then it is a primitive root $\pmod{p}$.

Well, if $g$ is a primitive root $\pmod{p^2}$, this means that:

$$g^{p-2} \equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$$

and $\forall n < p-2$, $g^n \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$.

I want to show that $g^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $\forall m < p-1, g^m \not\equiv \pmod{p}$

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2):

We have $g$ a primitive root of $p^2$ if $g$ has order $\varphi(p^2)=p(p-1)$ modulo $p^2$.

We want to show that $g$ has order $p-1$ modulo $p$. Suppose to the contrary that $g$ has order $k$ modulo $p$, where $1\le k\lt p-1$. Then $g^k\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. So $g^k=1+tp$ for some $t$. It follows (binomial theorem) that $(g^k)^p\equiv 1\pmod {p^2}$, contradicting the fact that $g$ has order $p(p-1)$ modulo $p^2$.

**Remark:** It is hard to answer your specific question, about where one goes from here. For the OP started with the incorrect assertion that $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p^2$ means that $g^{p-2}\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$ and $\dots$. The correct start would use $g^{p(p-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$ and $\dots$.

Comment: A different proof would go like this: since $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p^2$, then for every $(n,p^2)=1$ there is an $x$ such that $g^x\equiv n\pmod{p^2}$. In particular, for every $(n,p)=1$ there is an $x$ such that $g^x\equiv1\pmod p$. Thus $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ as well. (This proof relies upon a characterization of primitive roots, while yours is nice as it relies only upon their definition.)

Comment: OP had started an order argument, so I thought that carrying it out might be useful.